# How to combine Kotlin flows only when the first is emitting a (not null) value, unsubscribing the second one if it is not?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow, kotlinx.coroutines.channels

What I'm trying to achieve is that `flowB` is just (re)subscribed when `flowA` emits a value different of `null`. But there is no standard way to do that (as I can see).

In my scenario, `flowB` is expensive to keep emitting values without need, so what I need is a way to unsubscribe from it when `flowA` is equal to `null`, but resubscribe when it has a (not `null`) value.

If I use something like `takeWhile` (testing for `null` values) before `combine`, what happens is that `flowA` completes in the first negative result and it will not receive updates anymore.

With `filterNotNull` I cannot achieve what I'm trying to do either, because the streaming will keep running with previous values (it will not stop when a `null` is received).

Anyone has any suggestions on how to achieve that with the standard operators?

Or it should be done as a new (custom) operator (like `combineWhenNotNull`), for instance? Any tips on how to achieve this behavior?

```kotlin
flowA
  .combine(flowB) { a, b ->
    if (a != null) {
      Log.d(TAG, "$a -> $b")
    }
  }
```

This is the base logic of the streaming, but this way `flowB` keeps emitting values, even when `flowA` is emitting `null` (that is what I want to avoid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flatMapLatest`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html)

```
flowA
    .flatMapLatest { a ->
        if (a == null) {
            emptyFlow()
        } else {
            flowB.onEach { b -> Log.d(TAG, "$a -> $b") }
        }
    }
```